# What is the fully-qualified type name of the value returned by put_back?

Tags: rust, rust-itertools

I am trying to create a struct that will hold an iterator returned by `itertools::put_back`. I do not know the type name to use for the struct member.

Here is how I obtain the iterator over a `String`:

```rust
use itertools::put_back; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let hello = "Hello world".to_owned();
    let hello_iter = hello.chars();
    let mut putback_iterator = put_back(hello_iter);
}
```

Here is the struct definition:

```rust
pub struct ParserEventIterator {
    char_iter: itertools::PutBack</* What DO I PUT HERE??? */>,
}
```

What is the type for `putback_iterator` in this case? I've tried:

```
itertools::PutBack<<std::string::String as Trait>::IntoIter>
```

Comment: Applying the duplicate: `itertools::PutBack<std::str::Chars<'_>>`

Comment: Thank you ! I was looking for a general way to find out type names and searched for such a question, but that question did not pop up.